# isGrounded by Rigidbody and CapsuleCollider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

tried different Ray length, still does not work!! how to configure it correctly? Here is the code part related to the jump

```
    bool isRolling = false;
    bool wannaJump = false;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
       rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0, Physics.gravity.y * 4, 0), ForceMode.Acceleration);

        if (wannaJump && isGrounded())
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0, JumpSpeed, 0), ForceMode.Impulse);
            wannaJump = false;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (isGrounded())
        {
           if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > 0)
           wannaJump = true;
        }        
    }

    bool isGrounded()
    {
        return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 0.05f);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Please provide some more details about specifically what your problem is

Comment: The character does not jump, because boll false with any length of the ray under the Collider. In terms of eliminating errors in other lines of code, removed bool isGrounded. The character began to jump (infinitely of course). So the error is in the method ssGrounded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in your IsGrounded Method.

instead of casting a ray from the bottom of the object it gets cast from the center.

I would reccomend creating a Vector3 that defines the bottom of the object and casting the ray from there instead of transform.position.

it should work if you use the following variable:

Vector3 playerBottom = new Vector3(transform.x, transform.y - (transform.localScale.y / 2), transform.z);

the IsGrounded Method should initialize the Raycast on the playerBottom variable instead of transform.position

you should also make sure that the Ray does not interact with the playermodel itself. just give the Player a Layer Mask and make the raycast Ignore said Layer Mask.

For More Information about that:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

I hope that helps!